# Iterating through bytes by 2 starting from 0

Tags: javascript, node.js

How do you iterate through an array of bytes like:

```
var data = new Buffer("0A0B0C0D", "hex");

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  console.log( data[i] ); // will iterate 1 by 1. Not what I wanted
  console.log( data[i+=1] ); // tried
  console.log( data[(i+=1)-1] ); // tried
}
```

I just want to iterate through it and get results like: `0A 0C` and `0B 0D`.
How can I do both of this?

Is a for loop okay? Should I use something else? Any suggestion for better performance are also welcome.

---

**update**

I forgot to say that I have to do the actual `i++` because I have to go through each byte, but I also want to be able to access the index for the buffer by twos.

So all I need is if the `i` is `0` then I need to get the `data[i]`.

If the `i` is `2` then I need to get the `data[i+1]`. So on and so forth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it.

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i+=2)
```

Your other attempts didn't actually change the value of i.  They just told the pointer to look in a different place.

EDIT:
Try this:

```
var data = new Buffer("0A0B0C0D", "hex");
var xx=0;
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  console.log( data[i] ); // will iterate 1 by 1. Not what I wanted
  console.log( data[xx] );
  xx++;
  console.log( data[xx] );
  xx=0;
}
```

Although, I don't exactly see how that's going to help.  That will just check  xx and xx+1 for however many times i is run.
If you wanted to check i, and i+1 at the same time, then start anew with i+2, the original answer I gave should do the trick.

Comment: Sorry my mistake, I was actually really aiming for that. I just want to point to another place that is skipping by 2. Any idea on that?

Comment: console.log( data[i+=1]
Why do you need the +=?  Why don't you just say i+1?
Then, skip by two for the next set...

Comment: the problem with data[i+1]. Is it doesnt start on the 0 index. I need to start on the 0 index too. I have 3 logs on the loop, 1 for the current index, 1 for the even index, 1 for the odd index based on the current index.

Comment: Then add another counter within the loop that you update manually.
xx=0;  Within the loop, check xx, xx+1, and reset to xx=0 on each itteration.